# what is single face electrode on F72 series capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, tantalum

I'm looking at kyocera-avx F72 series capacitor. I'm puzzled at the last 3 numbers of the part number AQ2 or Q2 which say single face electrode. I thought capacitor come with 2 electrode be it polarized or non polarized. What is single face electrode? A new technology?

https://www.kyocera-avx.com/products/tantalum/smd-tantalum-mno2/f72-series/

Answer (score 0):

This picture from their [datasheet](https://datasheets.kyocera-avx.com/F72-F75.pdf) seems pretty clear to me, two variants have different shape of metallisation:

[image]

With double face electrodes you can solder them either way, but with single face electrodes only one way.

Comment: Any advantage/disadv different between these two?